# Different modules name for cocoadpods and carthage

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, carthage

I'm working on SDK that uses 3-rd party dependencies to:
https://github.com/delannoyk/AudioPlayer

The problem is when you install it with **Carthage** while I'm working on that framework name is `AudioPlayer.framework`, but when installing with **Cocoapods** this is `KDEAudioPlayer.framework` and I want to specify imports in my header `SDK.h` file as:

`@import AudioPlayer;`

And when installing with carthage it works, but installing with cocoapods this raise Build error. And then going further how to use it in code with for example:

`func audioPlayer(_ audioPlayer: AudioPlayer, didUpdateProgressionTo time: TimeInterval, percentageRead: Float) {`

Should I use `AudioPlayer` or `KDEAudioPlayer`? How to make it works?

Comment: Just decide whether you want to use Carthage or Cocoapods for importing that specific module and use the module name accordingly. Moreover, you should ask the question of why that module has different names for the different dependency manager from the developer of that framework on GitHub, (s)he's the only one able to answer the question.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I cannot really do this. Whenever sb want to use my SDK I cannot force him to use Carthage or Cocoapods. It's not for me to decide.

Comment: It would be nice to add that information to your question as well :) Does your own SDK support Cocoapods and Carthage? If yes, then just assume the name of `AudioPlayer` that is used with that specific dependency manager. But again, the only real solution would be opening a GitHub issue and asking for the developer of `AudioPlayer` to fix this issue.